# Return true if comma separated values are within JSON array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am using the WP Rest API as a JSON resource to loop through news stories. My users are able to enter a comma separated list of values like this: `28, 21`

I then have a series of JSON objects I loop through and each one has a fields `categories` which takes the form:

`categories: [34, 28, 21]`

`categories: [34]`

`categories: [6, 9, 21]`

I want to be able to check *if the categories array contains any of the user values return true*

`if(inarray) { //process data } else {return false / carry on with loop}`

In the above use case - the first and third new stories would be shown but not the second as it doesn't contain `28` OR `21`

I have tried a few solutions but just need some guidance on this so pseudo is all I can provide :/

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: can't use jQuery.inArray() function ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this if else statement based on jQuery

```
if ($.inArray(21, [34, 28, 21]) >= 0) {
            alert("found element");
        }else{
            alert("not found");
        }
```

Comment: That works well for one value but how do compare a string like `28, 21, 24` as the first parameter of the `inArray` value

Comment: You can use || condition. Otherwise not possible that